# PowerShell how to use Get-SCTenantEvent

Tags: powershell, office-365

I am trying to pull health data from a SharePoint Tenant using the Get-SCTenantEvent command. I do not have access to view this information on our organisations site, but i can see it on the Tenants site through delegated access. When we run the command however, it is failing.

```
$events = Get-SCTenantEvent -SCSession $O365Connection -Domains "clientdomain.onmicrosoft.com"
```

I am running the command using the normal Get-SCEvent on another SharePoint Online Instance and it works fine, its just when i try to access it using Delegated Access i have the problem. Do i need to be an administrator for the Instance i am going through as well as the site i am getting the data about with Delegated Access? Or can someone see a problem with the code? The domain name used is what displays on the Partners Interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation `You'll need to be a global administrator for an Office 365 Tenant or a delegated partner for an Office 365 tenant.`

I would test with global admin and see i get the results.

[A Powershell module for retrieving data from the Office 365 Service Communications API](https://github.com/mattmcnabb/O365ServiceCommunications)